# JComboBox setting label and value

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

Is it possible to set a value and a label to a `JComboBox` so I can show a label but get a value that is different?

For example in JavaScript I can do:

```
document.getElementById("myselect").options[0].value //accesses value attribute of 1st option
document.getElementById("myselect").options[0].text //accesses text of 1st option
```

Answer (score 32):

You can put any object inside of a JComboBox. By default, it uses the toString method of the object to display a label navigate in the combo box using the keyboard. So, the best way is probably to define and use appropriate objects inside the combo :

```
public class ComboItem {
    private String value;
    private String label;

    public ComboItem(String value, String label) {
        this.value = value;
        this.label = label;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return this.label;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return label;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, can show me a full example? I don't' understand how to put this object into a JComboBox...

Comment: @xdevel2000 Just create an aray of these objects and set it to the combobox ComboItem[] items = new ComboItem[]{new ComboItem("value1", "label1"),new ComboItem("value2", "label2")};  JComboBox cb = new JComboBox(items);

Comment: @kleopatra: then how do you do when the toString of an object is "foo", and you want to make it display "bar" in the combo? Using a renderer works. But if you hit B in the combo, it doesn't select anything. And if you hit F in the combo, it selects the item rendered as "bar". Which isn't acceptable. That's why I suggest using wrapper objects having an adequate toString method.

Comment: This. This should be the accepted answer. It solves the problem perfectly. Just add a toString method that returns what you want to show in the combo, then add the objects themselves to the combo.

Comment: Also see [this blogpost](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/02/18/combo-box-with-hidden-data/) which confirms what JB Nizet says. So basically, use the accepted answer if you want to display ordinary Strings in your combobox, or use a custom renderer along with a custom `KeySelectionManager`.

Answer (score 9):

Here's a utility interface and class that make it easy to get a combo box to use different labels.  Instead of creating a replacement `ListCellRenderer` (and risking it looking out of place if the look-and-feel is changed), this uses the default `ListCellRenderer` (whatever that may be), but swapping in your own strings as label text instead of the ones defined by `toString()` in your value objects.

```
public interface ToString {
    public String toString(Object object);
}

public final class ToStringListCellRenderer implements ListCellRenderer {
    private final ListCellRenderer originalRenderer;
    private final ToString toString;

    public ToStringListCellRenderer(final ListCellRenderer originalRenderer,
            final ToString toString) {
        this.originalRenderer = originalRenderer;
        this.toString = toString;
    }

    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(final JList list,
            final Object value, final int index, final boolean isSelected,
            final boolean cellHasFocus) {
        return originalRenderer.getListCellRendererComponent(list,
            toString.toString(value), index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
    }

}
```

As you can see the `ToStringListCellRenderer` gets a custom string from the `ToString` implementation, and then passes it to the original `ListCellRenderer` instead of passing in the value object itself.

To use this code, do something like the following:

```
// Create your combo box as normal, passing in the array of values.
final JComboBox combo = new JComboBox(values);
final ToString toString = new ToString() {
    public String toString(final Object object) {
        final YourValue value = (YourValue) object;
        // Of course you'd make your own label text below.
        return "custom label text " + value.toString();
    }
};
combo.setRenderer(new ToStringListCellRenderer(
        combo.getRenderer(), toString)));
```

As well as using this to make custom labels, if you make a `ToString` implementation that creates strings based on the system Locale,  you can easily internationalize the combo box without having to change anything in your value objects.

Comment: OK,but toString method from final ToString toString it's called every time when i'm  over comboBox with mouse.How do  i reduce the number of calls?

Comment: Nice try, it almost worked but it will fail miserably if you try using it with the generic version of JComboBox.

Answer (score 6):

> Please, can show me a full example?

Instances of `Enum` are particularly convenient for this, as [`toString()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#toString%28%29) "returns the name of this enum constant, as contained in the declaration."

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/** @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5661556 */
public class ColorCombo extends JPanel {

    private Hue hue = Hue.values()[0];

    public ColorCombo() {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(320, 240));
        this.setBackground(hue.getColor());
        final JComboBox colorBox = new JComboBox();
        for (Hue h : Hue.values()) {
            colorBox.addItem(h);
        }
        colorBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Hue h = (Hue) colorBox.getSelectedItem();
                ColorCombo.this.setBackground(h.getColor());
            }
        });
        this.add(colorBox);
    }

    private enum Hue {

        Cyan(Color.cyan), Magenta(Color.magenta), Yellow(Color.yellow),
        Red(Color.red), Green(Color.green), Blue(Color.blue);

        private final Color color;

        private Hue(Color color) {
            this.color = color;
        }

        public Color getColor() {
            return color;
        }
    }

    private static void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Color");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(new ColorCombo());
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                display();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [ListCellRenderer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ListCellRenderer.html) to achieve what you want. Make a class that extends `JLabel` and implements `ListCellRenderer`. Set that class as a renderer in your `JComboBox` using `setRenderer()` method. Now when you access values from your jcombobox it will be of type jlabel.

Comment: This will work, but will break keyboard navigation, which is based on the toString of the combo items.

Comment: @JB Nizet: then the keyboard navigation is broken ;-) The way to go is to fix it instead of dirty hacks in toString

Comment: @kleopatra: The keyboard navigation code is deeply hidden inside a non-accessible inner class of javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboUI, and there is no easy way, other than reimplementing it and coupling it to the renderer, of overriding it. I agree with your principle, but the design of this part of Swing makes it very very painful to follow this principle. I think a generic wrapper object redefining toString and delegating everything else (equals, hashCode) to the wrapped object is a better solution.

Comment: hmm ... doesn't it use the combo's KeySelectionManager?

Comment: checked: the ui queries the combo.selectWithKey which in turn delegates to its KeySelectionManager. So the clean solution is to set a well-behaved implementation of the manager (that is one which respects the actual string rep). And just noticed: SwingX has a but there as well, forgot to install a custom manager which knows about our StringValue :-) Thanks for bringing this up!

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**
Create a class with the two properties of the `JComboBox`, id, name for example

```
public class Product {
    private int id;
    private String name;


    public Product(){

    }

    public Product(int id, String name){        
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    //this method return the value to show in the JComboBox
    @Override
    public String toString(){
       return name;
    }

}
```

**Step 2**
In the design of the form, right click in the `JComboBox` and select Properties, now open the code tab and in the property Type Parameters write the name of the class, in our example it is Product.

[image]

**Step 3**
Now create a method that connects to the database with a query to generate a list of products, this method receives as a parameter a `JComboBox` object.

```
public void showProducts(JComboBox <Product> comboProduct){
    ResultSet res = null;
    try {
        Connection conn = new Connection();
        String query = "select id, name from products";
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.getConecction().prepareStatement(query);
        res = ps.executeQuery();
        while (res.next()) {
            comboProduct.addItem(new Product(res.getInt("id"), res.getString("name")));
        }
        res.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println("Error showing the products " + e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

**Step 4**
You can call the method from the form

```
public frm_products() {
    initComponents();

    Product product = new Product(); 

    product.showProducts(this.cbo_product);

}
```

Now you can access the selected id using `getItemAt` method

```
System.out.println(cbo_product.getItemAt(this.cbo_product.getSelectedIndex()).getId());
```