# New Option for Each Controller Found

Tags: java, arrays, jcombobox, jinput

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Values of JComboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650151/values-of-jcombobox)

I have a code like this:

```
import net.java.games.input.Controller;
import net.java.games.input.Controller.Type;
import net.java.games.input.ControllerEnvironment;

public class ControllerFinder
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            ControllerEnvironment ce = ControllerEnvironment.getDefaultEnvironment();
            Controller[] cs = ce.getControllers();
            for (int i = 0; i < cs.length; i++)
            {
                String name = cs[i].getName();
                Type type = cs[i].getType();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            System.err.println("No controller found");
        }
    }
}
```

How could I make a program that has a JComboBox and creates a new option in the

```
String[] {"...", "..."};
```

array for the JComboBox for each device found? Thanks!
P.S. I am using JInput.

Comment: I have reviewed that question, mine seems quite different.

Comment: Vincent Ramdhanie's answer works basically as-is for your problem, just use Controller instead of customer.

Comment: @user1832583 Is your requirement to populate the array at runtime??and also make its length dynamic ie; a dynamic array that can grow and shrink ??