# Stop OSX from Automatically re-Sizing JComboBox?

Tags: java, macos, swing, jcombobox, autosize

I created a program that deals with combo boxes, and I ran across a problem a Mac user showed me. Mac apparrently resizes JComboBox's and JButton's even if I set the width. The width of all the combo boxes on Windows are different since they are supposed to, but on OSX it's all the same width and size making it impossible to read half the entries of in the combo-box because it's all cut off when you try to select a selection. How can I fix or prevent this?

So my question is, how do you stop an operating system from auto-resizing the swing tools, or how do I make the selections in the JCombBox's readable and not cut off to like "Boxes" instead of "Bo...?"

Comment: Do you set a non-default LookAndFeel?

Comment: for better help sooner edit your question with a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: I don't believe I set the look and feel anywhere, I want it to have a native look for different operating systems, but not at the cost of its functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513), *don't set the width*; that is the purview of the UI delegate, `com.apple.laf.AquaComboBoxUI`. Instead, let the `JComboBox` calculate it's own preferred size based on the font metrics that inevitably vary from one platform to another.

If you still have problems, this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5663782/230513) may form the basis for your [sscce](http://sscce.org/).