# Draw in another component

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, components

I have a homework to do but there is not enough information and I'm stuck right now... Here is the issue, I have three classes :

- "ChoicePanel" extends JPanel and add buttons to select a color with a JComboBox

  ```
  public class ChoicePanel extends JPanel{

      Draw dessin;

      public ChoicePanel(Draw df) {
          dessin = df;
          ...
          // couleurs
          final JComboBox<String> couleurs = new JComboBox<>(new String[] {"bleu", "jaune", "rouge"});
          add(couleurs);
      }

      /** Know what color is selected */
      private Color determineCouleur(int indice){
          switch (indice) {
          case 0:
              return Color.BLUE;
          case 1:
              return Color.YELLOW;
          case 2:
              return Color.RED;
          default:
              return Color.BLACK;
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- "Draw" extends JPanel and stock all outline and paint them
- "Main" create the frame with those classes included

I have to set Draw as a MouseMotionListener but i can't get the color selected in ChoixePanel because the JComobox is created in the construcor and I can't set it to a field.
So how can I check ChoicePanel's buttons values from Draw ?

Every answer will be very helpfull !

Comment: You are passing `Draw` to `ChoicePanel` and holding it as a field. That field already has access to `ChoicePanel`'s variable's.

Comment: Also, when posting a HW question, it's a good idea to tell what you can change in the code and what not, and if there are classes you are not allowed to use.

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14887457/230513).

Comment: I didn't know that, so how can I get "couleurs"  var from Draw ? 
For the second comment : I can't add fields like Color in Draw.
Also, determinerCouleur have to stay private

Comment: `couleurs` is in `ChoicePanel`, you don't get it "*from Draw*". Maybe post the relevant parts of `Draw`.

Comment: (Tip: use @<username> to reply to comments.)

Comment: @user1803551, the MouseMotionListener is Draw so in Draw in MouseDragged, how can i get the color ?

Comment: @trashgod, I can't create a private class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal of the exercise may be to help you learn about [scope and access](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) in Java. Let's refactor the example seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5663782/230513) to meet your requirements.

- A `ChoicePanel` needs a way to update an instance of the `Draw` panel; you can pass a reference as a parameter to the panel's constructor or the factory method shown below.

  ```
  public static JPanel create(Draw draw) {…}
  ```
- In the combo's action listener set the color on `draw`; optionally invoke `draw.repaint()` if the change is not to a [bound property](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setBackground-java.awt.Color-) such as background color.

  ```
  Hue h = (Hue) colors.getSelectedItem();
  draw.setBackground(h.getColor());
  //draw.repaint();
  ```
- Because `Draw` may contain no components, override `getPreferredSize()` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7229662/230513) and below.
- > I can't create a private class…

  For convenience in running the example below, `ChoicePanel` and `Draw` are included as `private static` members. Simply move each to its own file, absent the [modifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html), to get stand-alone classes having *package-private* access from `Main`.

  ```
  JFrame f = new JFrame("Main");
  Draw d = new Draw();
  f.add(d, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  f.add(ChoicePanel.create(d), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
  ```

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/5663782/230513
 */
public class Main {

    private static class ChoicePanel {

        public static JPanel create(Draw draw) {
            JPanel p = new JPanel();
            final JComboBox colors = new JComboBox();
            for (Hue h : Hue.values()) {
                colors.addItem(h);
            }
            colors.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
                Hue h = (Hue) colors.getSelectedItem();
                draw.setBackground(h.getColor());
            });
            p.add(colors);
            return p;
        }
    }

    private static class Draw extends JPanel {

        public Draw() {
            this.setBackground(Hue.values()[0].getColor());
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(320, 240);
        }
    }

    public enum Hue {

        Cyan(Color.cyan), Magenta(Color.magenta), Yellow(Color.yellow),
        Red(Color.red), Green(Color.green), Blue(Color.blue);

        private final Color color;

        private Hue(Color color) {
            this.color = color;
        }

        public Color getColor() {
            return color;
        }
    }

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Main");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Draw d = new Draw();
        f.add(d, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        f.add(ChoicePanel.create(d), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            new Main().display();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @trahgod, i'm going to try this :)